# python - how to add unicode literal to a variable?

Tags: python, unicode-literals

I've seen some examples like this:

```
for name in os.listdir(u'somedir') :
```

my problem is that I'm getting the somedir as a variable, so how can I append the 'u' literal?

something like

```
for name in ops.listdir(u+somedir)
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the source of `somedir` doesn't provide it as a Unicode string (`isinstance(somedir, unicode)` is False) then you should decode it by providing an appropriate character encoding (it depends on where the bytes come from):

```
unicode_somedir = somedir.decode(encoding)
```

Answer (score 7):

Given a raw byte string, you can convert it to a `unicode` object (Python 2.x) or a `str` object (Python 3.x) by decoding it:

```
for name in ops.listdir(somedir.decode("utf-8")):
```

Use whatever encoding the byte string is encoded in instead of `"utf-8"`.  If you omit the encoding, Python's standard encoding will be used (`ascii` in 2.x, `utf-8` in 3.x).

See the [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) ([3.x](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/unicode.html)) for further information.

Answer (score 5):

unicode(somedir)

e.g. use the builtin function

Comment: Note that in general you will need to provide an encoding, and that the `encode()` and `decode()` methods are the preferred way to ocnvert between raw byte strings and Unicode strings.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone comes across this post like I did:

A little hack you can do is `(u'%s' % somedir)`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to use unicode function as follows:

x = unicode('1.2.3.4')

print x

u'1.2.3.4'

type(x)

> type 'unicode'

It shows type as unicode now.